# Why doesn't my datatable.compute sum code work. How do I add the filter code to the Sum function

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

Here's my visual basic code. I have an Access database. Income table with Income Amount, MonthYr, etc columns. I have verified data is in the table and is being loaded into the dataset. There is definitely a "January 2018" value in the MonthYr column. And I also have decimal numbers in the Income amount column.

```
Dim sum = IncomeTable.Compute("SUM(Income Amount)", "MonthYr = January 2018")
```

'code above causes this error: Missing operand after '2018' operator.

```
Dim sum = IncomeTable.Compute("SUM(Income Amount)", "MonthYr = 'January 2018'")
```

'code above causes this error: Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.

```
Dim sum = IncomeTable.Compute("SUM(Income Amount)", "MonthYr = [January 2018]")
```

' code above causes this error: Cannot find column [January 2018].

-In Access, The Income Amount column is currency datatype, and MonthYr column is short text datatype

-I have tried various other things like using an _underscore to replace the spaces in column name and in "January 2018"
-I have been looking all over msdn and google and tried every variation of the code I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is totally off - wonder where you got that from.

It could be:

```
Dim SumAmount As Currency
SumAmount = DSum("[Income Amount]", "IncomeTable", "MonthYr = 'January 2018'")
```

**In VB**:

Open a recordset:

```
"Select Sum([Income Amount]) From IncomeTable Where MonthYr = 'January 2018'"
```

Comment: Thanks bUT I forgot to specify this is Visual Basic, connected to Access database. The DSUM function is not available when I use your example. The  DSUM function is used within Access, right?

Comment: I need to total a column within the dataset only, not in Access. I'm filling the dataset with specific data, then trying to get the sum of column "Income Amount" where "monthYr" = "January 2018". The datatable.compute function is all I could come up with and its not working.

Comment: Then open a recordset using the SQL I've added to the answer.